'Opposite' property of finitely generated projective modules.
I recently went to a talk and the speaker stated that over a commutative ring R, for any finitely generated projective module P, there exists some finitely generated projective module K such that
$$ P \otimes_R K \simeq R \oplus L$$
for some R-module L.
This is not obvious to me at all, and any insight in said statement would be appreciated.

Try $K=P^$ and use the fact that $P\otimes_R P^$ has a well-known form.

@CaptainLama This is isomorphic to the endomorphisms of $P$, isn't it?

Indeed. Either use that fact, or try to define a surjective map $P\otimes_R P^*\to R$ and use that $R$ is projective. You will need the hypothesis that $P$ is faithful though.

$P=0$ is a counterexample. Please add the missing assumptions.

Indeed, if $P$ is faithful this can be done quite obviously, but this assumption was not given. By the given counterexample of $P = 0$ I assume this must be an assumption which was forgotten.

I have posted the answers that were given in the comments as, well, an answer. Comments should not be used for that. See How do comments work for more information.

We need to assume that $P$ has positive rank. Then the canonical homomorphism $P^* \otimes P \to R$ is surjective: Since $P$ is locally free of positive rank, this can be reduced to the case $P = R^n$ with $n > 0$, where it's clear. Since $R$ is projective, we get $P^* \otimes P \cong R \oplus K$ for some module $K$.
